# Finite element method: proof of the inverse inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, finite-element-method

I am studying the condition number of the stiffness matrix and I am facing some problems with the proof of the inverse inequality:

$$|| \nabla v_h ||_0^2 \le C h^{-2} || v_h ||_0^2.$$

Using the fact that the triangulation is quasi-uniform and working on the reference element, the author writes that the function

$$ \frac{\int_{\hat{K}} | \nabla \hat{v}|^2}{\int_{\hat{K}} \hat{v}^2} $$

is bounded and therefore we have that

$$ (1) \int_K | \nabla v_h|^2 \le C||B_K^{-1}||^2 \int_K v_h^2 \le \frac{C}{\rho_K^2} \int_K v_h^2. $$

I am not able to understand how to get $(1)$. He says he uses some semi-norm transformation but I cannot understand. Do you have any reference for this?

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at Theorem 3.1.2 p117 and Theorem 3.1.3 p120 in the book  [Philippe G. Ciarlet, *The Finite Element Method for Elliptic Problems*.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0898715148)

Comment: Are you able to offer a summary for those who do not have access the book? After all, this website discourages questions from saying only "how do you solve exercise 3.5b in this certain textbook." Your answer is appreciated, but I imagine it should be held to the same standard.